# How to use bitbucket pipeline to generate war file and copy it to downloads?

Tags: maven, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to use bitbucket as a maven repository for a personal project. My plan is to use bitbucket pipelines to build the project and copy the war file to the downloads page. After the build finishes successfully, I get the following message:

`Building war: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war`

but when the second pipeline is run to copy the war, I get the following:

`File opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war doesn't exist.`

Also the artifacts tab is empty.

[image]

bitbucket_pipelines.yaml:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
              - mvn clean compile package
            artifacts:
              - opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war
    - step:
        name: Generate and deploy war
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.2
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
              FILENAME: "opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war
```

You have removed the `"/"` at the beginning of the path string, which makes it a **relative path** to the current directory. Try something like this, to use an absolute path:

```
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war
```

However, instead of using a hard-coded full path, there is a better way to use a relative path with some environment variables, and also to add some temporary debug lines to verify the path. Consider something like this:

```yaml
script:
  - mvn clean compile package

  # Now verify the path of the built WAR output file
  - echo $BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR # Debug: Print the Git clone directory
  - pwd # Debug: Print the current working directory
  - find "$(pwd -P)" -name todoey.war # Debug: Show the full file path of todoey.war, from the current working directory
  - echo "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war" # Debug: Print the resolved path of todoey.war

artifacts:
  - "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war"
```

```yaml
- pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.2
    variables:
      BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
      BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
      FILENAME: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war"
```

`$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR` is a pre-defined environment variable to your project's 'Git clone' root folder: It's described here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-in-pipelines/

---

Update 5 December 2022: The guideline on [Bitbucket Artifacts](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/) says that you must only use relative paths for the `artifacts:` step, but you can use full paths for the `pipe:` step. So something like this:

```yaml
image: maven:3.6.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
            name: Build and Test
            caches:
              - maven
            script:
              - mvn clean compile package
            artifacts:
              # Use a relative path here
              - build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war
    - step:
        name: Generate and deploy war
        script:
          - pipe: atlassian/bitbucket-upload-file:0.3.2
            variables:
              BITBUCKET_USERNAME: $BITBUCKET_USERNAME
              BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD: $BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD
              # Use the full path here, with an environment variable
              FILENAME: "$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war"
```

Comment: FYI the `/build` part of the path is also captured in `$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR`, so this will resolve to `/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/build/todoey-be/target/todoey.war`

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that your path is correct, try to clean bitbucket maven cache.
You can find it on `Pipelines -> Caches`